# What are best mobile navigation practices for infinite scrolling pages with a deep hierarchy?

Tags: usability, mobile, navigation, mobile-web

A site is composed of many infinite scroll pages each with several layers of content.  **What are best navigation architecture practices for infinite scroll sites on mobile devices enabling the highest level of usability?** Users should be able to skip through content (without scrolling all the way down) yet also know where they are within the page and site at any point in time.  Here's an example of one possible solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if these are the best alternatives but it's something worth discussing.

[image]

The first one shows a kind of progress indicator usually seen in carousels. The section you are viewing is marked with color and the title is displayed at the top. You can tap on one of the dots to go to that section.

The second is an enriched scroll/tap bar that displays the categories. You can tap on one of the categories to scroll to that section. The little black line is where you are inside the current category.

Comment: This is a very good idea, and quite close to what I was thinking. What we've done is organized 8 sections into 3 groups, but I really like this alternative.